# Tree conflict when integrating revision in working copy

Tags: svn

I have a strange tree conflict when integrating revisions into a working copy and I do not understand why ... :(

The development is done in /trunk/project.
Revision 619 was branched to /branches/divB/majorwork in order to implement major changes. In parallel, working in trunk continued.
In revision 636 the branch was re-integrated into the trunk. svn:mergeinfo of "project" got the entry

```
/branches/divB/majorwork:620-635
```

Finally, in revision 680, a stable tag was created in /tags/v1.0

Now the HEAD is Rev 706 and I want to create /tags/v1.1 with just a small bugfixes backported to v1.0. The revisions I want to merge from trunk are 682-683.

Now I do the following:
1.) svn switch from my working copy to /tags/v1.0
2.) svn merge revisions 682-683 from /trunk/project into working copy.

However, intead that the small set of files is merged into my working copy, I get a tree conflict on the main directory "project": When I choose "Check for modifications", I get:

```
Path      Text status             Property status
---------+-----------------------+----------------
project   normal                  modified
project   missing, tree conflict
```

When I compare the "project" folder, I find that:

svn:mergeinfo : Working base:

```
/branches/divB/majorwork:620-635
```

svn:mergeinfo : Working copy

```
/branches/divB/majorwork:620-635
/trunk:682-683
```

I do not understand why I get a tree conflict here and what I am doing wrong. My intention was to merge the text files which have changed and then tag the working copy to /tags/v1.1

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I was really too dumb and missed the forest for the trees ...

I did merge from /trunk rather than /trunk/project ...